# Trim URL to ROOT/SUBDOMAIN with Excel

Tags: excel, url, excel-formula, trim

I need to trim URL's in Microsoft Excel to the root domain and to the subdomain.

**A1** = Contains `https://blog.example.com/page/`
**B1** = Should result in `example.com`
**C1** = Should result in `blog.example.com`

Two formulas removing http, https, .www and PATH. The first version (**B1**) should also remove SUBDOMAIN.

I only have *one* formula right now:

`=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2;"www.";"");SEARCH(":";A2)+3;SEARCH("/";SUBSTITUTE(A2;"www.";"");9)-SEARCH(":";A2)-3)`

`https://example.com/page/page` results in `example.com`
`http://www.example.com/page/page` results in `example.com`
`http://blog.example.com/page/` results in `blog.example.com`
`example.com/page`  results in  `#VALUE!`
`www.example.com/page`  results in   `#VALUE!`

As you can see in the sample above I get good results. But it dosen't work without http or https. Also this version keeps subdomain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this in B1,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1, 1, IFERROR(FIND("//", A1)+1, 0), TEXT(,))&"/", FIND("/", REPLACE(A1, 1, IFERROR(FIND("//", A1)+1, 0), TEXT(,))&"/"), LEN(A1), TEXT(,)), CHAR(46), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A1))), LEN(A1)*2)), CHAR(32), CHAR(46))
```

.... and this in C1,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1, 1, IFERROR(FIND("//", A1)+1, 0), TEXT(,))&"/", FIND("/", REPLACE(A1, 1, IFERROR(FIND("//", A1)+1, 0), TEXT(,))&"/"), LEN(A1), TEXT(,)), "www.", TEXT(,))
```

[image: replace_strip_url]

Comment: Works flawlessly!

Comment: This works really well. The only thing is that for linkw like www.dailymail.co.uk it changes it to co.uk where it should be dailymail.co.uk.

Answer (score 3):

If your version of excel has **FILTERXML** function (which can be found in `Excel 365, Excel 2019, Excel 2016, and Excel 2013`),

Suppose your URLs are in range `A2:A29`

To find **Sub Domain**, enter the following formula in Cell `B2` and drag it down:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(MID(A2,FIND("//",A2)+2,LEN(A2)),A2),"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","t/s[1]"),"www.","")
```

> For the logic behind this formula you may give a read to this article: [Extract Words with FILTERXML](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/).

To find **Root Domain**, enter the following formula in Cell `C2` and drag it down:

```
=IF((SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(B2,ROW($1:$100),1)="."))-IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(RIGHT(B2,8),ROW($1:$8),1)="."))=3,2,SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(RIGHT(B2,8),ROW($1:$8),1)="."))))>0,RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND(".",B2)),B2)
```

> I used the Sub Domain from the first formula to find Root Domain. The trick is to find out if the component of the URL before the first dot `.` is the root domain or sub domain, and take action accordingly.

[image: Solution]

Sample Data

```
| URL                              | Sub                 | Root           |
|----------------------------------|---------------------|----------------|
| https://example.com/page/page    | example.com         | example.com    |
| http://www.example.com/page/page | example.com         | example.com    |
| http://blog.example.com/page/    | blog.example.com    | example.com    |
| example.com/page                 | example.com         | example.com    |
| www.example.com/page             | example.com         | example.com    |
| blog.test.com                    | blog.test.com       | test.com       |
| http://blog.test.com             | blog.test.com       | test.com       |
| test.com                         | test.com            | test.com       |
| http://blog.test.uk.net/         | blog.test.uk.net    | test.uk.net    |
| https://test.cn                  | test.cn             | test.cn        |
| www.test.com                     | test.com            | test.com       |
| http://www.test.com              | test.com            | test.com       |
| https://www.test.com             | test.com            | test.com       |
| test.co.uk                       | test.co.uk          | test.co.uk     |
| https://test.co.uk               | test.co.uk          | test.co.uk     |
| www.test.co.uk                   | test.co.uk          | test.co.uk     |
| http://www.test.co.uk            | test.co.uk          | test.co.uk     |
| https://www.test.co.uk           | test.co.uk          | test.co.uk     |
| blog.123.firm.in                 | blog.123.firm.in    | 123.firm.in    |
| http://example.test.co.uk        | example.test.co.uk  | test.co.uk     |
| https://test.7.org.au            | test.7.org.au       | 7.org.au       |
| test.example.org.nz/page         | test.example.org.nz | example.org.nz |
| http://example.com/test          | example.com         | example.com    |
| https://example.com/test         | example.com         | example.com    |
| http://blog.example.com/page/    | blog.example.com    | example.com    |
| example.com/page                 | example.com         | example.com    |
| www.example.com/page             | example.com         | example.com    |
| http://blog.1.co.uk              | blog.1.co.uk        | 1.co.uk        |
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the static parts ROW($1:$100) and ROW($1:$8)? I assume $1:$100 stands for $header-title:$lastrow. But why rows 1:8?

Answer (score 2):

**Subdomain** - it's [Jeeped's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39222036), but I've added support for blank cells, because the original version outputted "/":

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), "", SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1, 1, IFERROR(FIND("//", A1)+1, 0), TEXT(,))&"/", FIND("/", REPLACE(A1, 1, IFERROR(FIND("//", A1)+1, 0), TEXT(,))&"/"), LEN(A1), TEXT(,)), "www.", TEXT(,)))
```

**Domain** - a version [from MrExcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/686548-remove-all-characters-url-except-root-domain-domain-extension-post3397441.html#post3397441) that supports international domains (e.g. this.co.uk). But unlike Jeeped's version it doesn't support 1 word TLDs like **www.this.co** or **test.this.co** - does anyone know how to fix this? For now I use a helper row at least for "www":

```
=IF(LEFT(a1,LEN("www."))="www.",RIGHT(a1,LEN(a1)-LEN("www.")), a1)
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IFERROR(MID(b1,FIND("://",b1)+3,99),b1))&"/","/",REPT(" ",99)),99))),".",REPT(" ",99)),99*(2+(LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IFERROR(MID(b1,FIND("://",b1)+3,99),b1))&"/","/",REPT(" ",99)),99)))&".",".",REPT(" ",99)),198)))=2))))," ",".")
```

It worked on:

```
            A                   |           B           |       C
(blank)                         |   ""                  |   ""                          
blog.test.com                   |   blog.test.com       |   test.com
http://blog.test.com            |   blog.test.com       |   test.com
test.com                        |   test.com            |   test.com
http://test.com                 |   test.com            |   test.com
https://test.com                |   test.com            |   test.com
www.test.com                    |   test.com            |   test.com
http://www.test.com             |   test.com            |   test.com
https://www.test.com            |   test.com            |   test.com
test.co.uk                      |   test.co.uk          |   test.co.uk
http://test.co.uk               |   test.co.uk          |   test.co.uk
https://test.co.uk              |   test.co.uk          |   test.co.uk
www.test.co.uk                  |   test.co.uk          |   test.co.uk
http://www.test.co.uk           |   test.co.uk          |   test.co.uk
https://www.test.co.uk          |   test.co.uk          |   test.co.uk
example.test.co.uk              |   example.test.co.uk  |   test.co.uk
http://example.test.co.uk       |   example.test.co.uk  |   test.co.uk
https://example.test.co.uk      |   example.test.co.uk  |   test.co.uk
example.com/test                |   example.com         |   example.com
http://example.com/test         |   example.com         |   example.com
https://example.com/test        |   example.com         |   example.com
http://blog.example.com/page/   |   blog.example.com    |   example.com
example.com/page                |   example.com         |   example.com
www.example.com/page            |   example.com         |   example.com
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

**For B1 (Extracting root domain), If A1 is complete URL:**

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(".",$A1),""),REPLACE(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(".",$A1),""),1,FIND("/",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(".",$A1),"")),""),""),"/","")
```