# Get domain WITHOUT subdomain in Excel?

Tags: excel

Can someone please give me the excel formula for extracting domain from a URL WITHOUT subdomain ? I've been searching for like 30+ minutes but all formulas include the subdomain too ..

This is what I want:

```
https://login.yahoo.com/config/login >>> yahoo.com
https://my.adobeconnect.com/system/login/ok >>> adobeconnect.com
http://www.pge.com/ >>> pge.com
https://secure.indeed.com/account/register >>> indeed.com
http://shop1.frys.com//wf >>> frys.com
```

EDIT:

Nevermind, I found the answer here:

[Trim URL to ROOT/SUBDOMAIN with Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221589/trim-url-to-root-subdomain-with-excel)

Comment: As author, unless there is reason to maintain this post, you can always delete.  I am not suggesting this, just pointing it out as an option.

Comment: I think it might be good to leave it in case someone else searches for the same issue, this post can increase the chance that they find the solution instead of creating another post (like me)