# Remove extra letters from link in Excel cell

Tags: excel

I have 100 000 links in excel doc and trying to extract just domains from those links. Example:

```
https://smallbusiness.chron.com/entrepreneurs-contribute-78923.html
```

I want to cut everything after **//** to **.com** to stay **smallbusiness.chron.com**
Is there any formula which can i apply in Excel or any idea of VBA?

Comment: you are probably looking to combine [`MID`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-D5F9E25C-D7D6-472E-B568-4ECB12433028) and [`FIND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-C7912941-AF2A-4BDF-A553-D0D89B0A0628)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim URL to ROOT/SUBDOMAIN with Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221589/trim-url-to-root-subdomain-with-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are a great tool for extracting data in situations like this, but they are tricky to implement in excel. I would refer you to this question on how to [implement in-cell or VBA regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) tools.

I like to use https://regex101.com/ with help on determining how to use regular expressions.